# Adding a non-laravel package to my Laravel project with composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

When using Laravel I am aware of the steps to follow to use a 3rd party library in my project using composer:

1. Add the package to composer.json:

   `"require": {
        "zizaco/confide": "3.2.x"
    }`
2. Run `composer update` to install the package
3. Add to the providers and alias arrays in `config/app.php`

I am trying to do the same with [highchartsphp](https://github.com/ghunti/HighchartsPHP). Installing via composer is simple enough but there are no instructions on how to use this package with Laravel. How to load the correct file and how to I instantiate the class as described in the readme? Is it just a case of adding it to the providers and aliases and then doing `$chart = new HighChart();` wherever I want?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is not a Laravel package, so you don't have Service Provider nor Alias to setup, but this is a PHP package and since you use Composer to install it, it is already autoloaded, so you can just:

Add the package to your composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "ghunti/highcharts-php": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

Run

```
composer dumpautoload
```

And instantiate it:

```
$chart = new Ghunti\HighchartsPHP\Highchart();
```

Or use it in the top of your php:

```
use Ghunti\HighchartsPHP\Highchart;
```

And you should be able to:

```
$chart = new Highchart(Highchart::HIGHSTOCK);
```

Anywhere in your project and it should work.

You can create an alias in `app/config/app.php` for it if you prefer to use it this way:

```
'Highchart' => 'Ghunti\HighchartsPHP\Highchart'
```

But you will still have to instantiate it

```
$chart = new Highchart();
```

You won't able to use it as in Laravel

```
Highchart::doWhatever();
```

Unless you create a ServiceProvider yourself, of course.

Comment: Trying this Laravel returns a `Class 'HighChart' not found` error. I have run `dump-autoload`

Comment: Yeah, the library is namespaced, just edited to show how to use it.

Comment: Is it possible to add an alias for this namespace so I can just reference the classname?

Comment: I see, so the `aliases` array in `app.php` can't be used unless it's a Laravel package? Many thanks.